Tailwind sidebar behind relative elements
I'm using Tailwind to show a Sidebar on the left, but I have on the right side (outside the sidebar) some position relative elements, and when I open the sidebar, I can see them for a moment on top of the sidebar. When this is open, those elements look fine, behind the sidebar. How to fix it?
My code doesn't really have anything special, just the sidebar from Tailwind (https://flowbite.com/docs/components/sidebar/) and some div with an absolute element inside that needs to be relative:
<div
        className={`inset-0 z-40 flex transition-transform ${
          isOpen ? '' : '-translate-x-full sm:translate-x-0'
        }`}
      >
        <nav
          className="sidebar fixed top-0 left-0 z-50 h-screen class"
          aria-label="Sidebar"
        >
          <div className="h-full overflow-y-auto">
            <ul className="space-y-2 font-medium">
              <li className="task cursor-pointer p-8" onClick={toggleSidebar}>
                <img src={TaskIcon} alt="Soar Task" className="icon" />
                Soar Task
              </li>
              {routes.map((route) => (
                <li
                  key={route.name}
                  className={`${location.pathname === route.path ? 'active' : ''}`}
                >
                  {location.pathname === route.path && (
                    <div className="marker"></div>
                  )}
                  <Link
                    to={route.path}
                    onClick={closeSidebar}
                    className="flex items-center group"
                  >
                    <img
                      src={route.icon}
                      alt={route.name + ' icon'}
                      className="icon"
                    />
                    <span className="ms-3">{route.name}</span>
                  </Link>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>

        {isOpen && (
          <div
            className="fixed inset-0 z-30 bg-black bg-opacity-50 sm:hidden"
            onClick={closeSidebar}
          ></div>
        )}
      </div>

      <div className="main-content">
        <div className="header-container flex gap-4 p-6 md:py-6 md:px-8">
          {/* this is where I have the other component */}
          <Header onToggleSidebar={toggleSidebar} />
        </div>

        {/* <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path="/settings" element={<Settings />} />
          <Route
            path="*"
            element={<div className="p-6">Nothing to see here</div>}
          />
        </Routes> */}
      </div>

